# Graphcool (Graphql): how to make exact filter in array of Id

Tags: filtering, graphql, graphcool

I have chat model

```
type Chat @model {
    id: ID! @isUnique
    name: String
    messages: [Message!]! @relation(name: "ChatMessages")
    users: [User!]! @relation(name: "ChatUser")
    createdAt: DateTime!
}
```

And I've created a chat with two people **["123", "234"]** and all was ok. But when I want to create a new group chat with three people where two of them already have a chat with themselves **["123", "234", "345"]**
I make a query for check is this chat exist with three people

```
query {
  allChats(filter:{
    users_every: {
        id_in: ["123", "234", "345"]
        }
      }
  ){
        id
        users{
         id
        }
      }
}
```

and I got response that this chat already exist, but here I have just two users not all of them

```
{
  "data": {
    "allChats": [
      {
        "id": "cjgxuub2351uj0187qeil548m",
        "users": [
          {
            "id": "123"
          },
          {
            "id": "234"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `every` suffix in `users_every` makes sure it matches all chats that have only users with ids from the `id_in` array. That's why you're getting chats with fewer users, because subsets match.

The solution:

```
query {
  allChats(
    filter: {
      AND: [
        { users_some: { id: "123" } },
        { users_some: { id: "234" } },
        { users_some: { id: "345" } },
        { users_every: { id_not_in: ["678", "910", ...] } }
      ]
    }
  ) {
    id
    users {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

The `users_some` filters make sure to select chats that have at least all those 3 users attached. The `users_every - id_not_in` is needed to exclude the chats with those three plus any other users.

In all honesty this seems a bit convoluted to me, and probably kinda unfeasible for an app with a large number of users. I'd love for graph.cool to implement some easier solution in the api.

As an alternative, you could just omit the `users_every` filter, and then, in your client app, pick from the results only the chat that has exactly `3` users.